# Create a rating system in java

Tags: java, statistics, rating

I am trying to rate an list of numbers eg. [297, 720, 840, 903, 1110, 1170] on a scale of 1 to 10 with 10 being the lowest and 1 being the highest number.

So list.get(0) would be 9/10 or 10/10 and list.get(2) would be 5 or 6 out of 10.

How can I do this in java?

Comment: Do you just want a sorted list? If so look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29 or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Comment: I already have the list sorted. I just need to figure how to give each number a rating out of 10

Comment: For the number in list.get(i), the rating is 10-i.

Comment: @SebastianRedl only if the list has exactly 10 items

Comment: what is the criteria for rating it out of 10. I mean the algorithm for this ?

Comment: Do you want `rate(i) = value(i) / max` or `rate(i) = i / count`? Or something completely else?

Comment: @Loenard yes. currently it only has 6 entries but that can change.

Comment: @Ankur that is part of what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Figure out the standard deviation for each number.  Use the formula rating = absolute value(standard deviation) * 5.  If the rating is more than 10, truncate to 10.  If the rating is less than 1, bump up to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest something like: `note = 10 - 9 * (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)`

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(297, 720, 840, 903, 1110, 1170);
    Collections.sort(list);
    Integer min = list.get(0);
    Integer max = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    List<Integer> notes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
        notes.add(10 - (int) 9.0 * (i - min) / (max - min));
    }
    System.out.println(notes);
```

Which gives:

```
[10, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This works alright so I'm going to use it. Thank you for your help